Apache Superset Multitenancy and Copy Project
We have a SaaS-based application where we develop features dynamically. We are currently searching for a reporting tool and have identified Apache Superset as a potential solution. However, we are facing challenges with configuring it for our specific project needs. Our data is stored in columns named s1, s2, n1, and n2, while Superset requires more generic column names. Additionally, we need support for multitenancy and the ability to copy configurations to other projects. Could you please guide us on how to address these issues?
We are expecting to manage user permissions on a project-by-project basis, configure widgets individually for each project, and have the ability to copy project configurations within a single installation.
